# How to fix wrong values being read from a file and stored in an array with a while loop?

Tags: c++

I am trying to loop through a file containing the numbers  3.8, 2.1, 2.9, 3.1,
2.0, 1.6, 3.5, 2.3, 2.1, 3.7, and 3.2 and store them in an array. I then have to add those numbers and take the average of that.  I have to use a while loop that loops until the end of file, but it is storing the wrong values in the array.

I have tried changing the order statements in the while loop, but it wont do anything. I have changed the file too and it did not help. I believe that it is in the while loop where it is messing up.

```
 subscript = 0;
 double gpasummer[subscript];
 fin >> gpa;

 while (!fin.eof())
 {
          gpasummer[subscript] = gpa;
          fin >> gpa;
          subscript = subscript +1;

 }
```

It should output the numbers in the file in the same order and then the average, but it only shows 3.8, 2.3, 2.3, 3.7, 3.2 and 0.0 (Which isnt even in the file), which makes the average wrong.

Comment: What do you think `double gpasummer[subscript];` does?

Comment: Declares an array with an index size that is equal to the subscript value?

Comment: Yes. And what is the subscript value at that time?

Comment: Zero, so the first value from the file is put into the array at index zero. Then it reads another value and increases the subscript size

Comment: Variable length arrays aren't valid C++.

Comment: **No.** It declares an array of size zero, and writes values past the end of the array, causing Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Ohhhhhh ok. So what would be the best way to define the size of an array when you do not know how many values will be put in it?

Comment: Two approaches: 1) use a more sophisticated container, like `std::vector`, or 2) keep track of the size of the array and number of elements stored in it, and when you run out of space, resize it (i.e. declare a bigger array and copy the contents of the old array into the new one-- which basically demands dynamic allocation).

Comment: ok Thank you for the help!

Comment: Info about using `eof()`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong